Why is there a drastic difference between new users in firebase vs new users in apple and google app stores?
I am looking at an app in firebase, we're monitoring new users, and historically we've pulled numbers from the play stores but pulling from our firebase analytics is easier via the connectors provided. We have noticed since doing this a difference between just adding the new users together from the play store numbers and the new users in firebase. I'd be ok with a difference of just a few users, but it is a lot and I don't really understand how that calculation could be that different from each of them.
Any resources I could be pointed to that show the way it is calculated would be helpful, google seems to love having a black box method of providing metrics.

Are you using Firebase Authentication and imported any of your users? There's a known bug where it doesn't exclude duplicate users from the count. Perhaps this is what you're seeing, if so Firebase Support can fix that.
You may want to contact them either way, as they have more insight into the data in your project and should be able to explain this discrepancy.
